# Is there any way to keep threads spawned in Rust - i.e., to "memoize" a thread object?

Tags: multithreading, rust, parallel-processing

On my runtime, I have the following Rust code:

```
pub fn reduce(heap: &Heap, prog: &Program, tids: &[usize], root: u64, debug: bool) -> Ptr {
  // Halting flag
  let stop = &AtomicBool::new(false);
  let barr = &Barrier::new(tids.len());
  let locs = &tids.iter().map(|x| AtomicU64::new(u64::MAX)).collect::<Vec<AtomicU64>>();

  // Spawn a thread for each worker
  std::thread::scope(|s| {
    for tid in tids {
      s.spawn(move || {
        reducer(heap, prog, tids, stop, barr, locs, root, *tid, debug);
      });
    }
  });

  // Return whnf term ptr
  return load_ptr(heap, root);
}
```

This will spawn many threads, in order to perform a parallel computation. The problem is, the `reduce` function is called thousands of times, and the overhead of spawning threads can be considerable. When I implemented the same thing in C, I just kept the threads open, and sent a message in order to activate them. In Rust, with the `std::thread::scope` idiom, I'm not sure how to do so. Is it possible to keep the threads spawned after the first call to reduce, by just modifying that one function? That is, without changing anything else on my code?

Comment: Have you considered using an async runtime, such as `tokio`, maybe with the help of [`tokio-scoped`](https://crates.io/crates/tokio-scoped)?

Comment: @rodrigo `tokio` looks great but I'd like to accomplish this without major changes to the codebase. All I need is to keep the threads alive. Not sure how that could be accomplished on `tokio`. Is that not possible with Rust's built-in scoped threads?

Answer (score 2):

Threads spawned using the `threads::scoped` api won't be able to outlive the the calling function. For long-running threads you'll need to spawn them using [std::thread::spawn](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.spawn.html).

Once you've made that change rustc will be very upset with you due to lifetime errors because you are sending non-static references into the spawned threads. Fixing those errors will require some changes. That path is long and full of learning.

If you want something that works really well and is simple, consider instead using the excellent [rayon](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/) crate. Rayon maintains it's own global thread pool so you don't have to.

Using rayon will look something like this:

```rust
tids.par_iter()
    .for_each(|tid| {
        reducer(heap, prog, tids, stop, barr, locs, root, *tid, debug);
    });
```